How do you modulate an image according to specific layers of a DNN
My lab uses DNNs (VGG, CLIP) to process the similarity of images of natural objects (dogs, trees, etc.). I'd like to modulate some images by scrambling (with some sort of gain function) the information for a specific layer, and then re-visualizing the image after that adjustment. Has this sort of thing been done?
